# Central Air and very hot upstairs, AC guy said no way to increase the small vent pipe going upstairs. How can I get it cooler? Floor vent?

Tags: hvac

I have a small 900sq foot two story A-frame type house.  The central AC ducts run upstairs but are very small, like 3" flexible tube that is bent when squeezing through the floor joist from the downstairs AC. There is no other option to re-rerun or make this pipe bigger because of the house layout, I had two HVAC guys over.  The AC is in a weird spot on the home.

How can I make the upstairs cooler?  My thoughts were:

1. installing a semi-permanent window fan to push the hot air outside while drawing the cooler AC air up the steps from downstairs. But will this kill my AC bill or no?
2. installing some type of floor penetration that has a fan in it that will push cool air from downstairs into the one upstairs room (do they make anything like this)?

What do you guys think?  I sleep upstairs so its an issue!

Comment: I know someone that had great success with register vents as it continuously pulls cooler air from the lower floors.  You test that with a common fan, some tape, and some flexible duct. If the pipe is really small, a computer fan (built for always being on) wired up to a phone charger might be a solution.

Comment: How many rooms/zones do you need to cover upstairs? If its only like one or two rooms, splitting them off into their own segment of the system by installing a mini-split might be a better option than trying to deal with ductopus nightmares...

Comment: turn your fan from `auto` to `on` to help balance the temp on both floors by mixing the air all the time instead of just when actively cooling.

Answer (score 1):

Installing a window fan would just end up blowing cool air out the window. I think your best bet would be to get a level to level fan that could be mounted through your floor to the ceiling below and suck air from there into your room. There are many types available and also many wall through wall fans that would work too.

Here's a picture o one type from Northern Tool, (which I am not connected with.).

[image]

Comment: Just a few thoughts. Can you partially restrict the downstairs vents increasing the pressure a small amount, this would cause more air to go up. Hot air rises pushing cold air down, you need enough pressure to overcome this. Also where is your  return vent(s). my neighbor closes off the lower one in the summer and the upper one in the winter. They also make boosters that will install in the duct. I use one here to boost the air flow to the four seasons room, works nicely.